# How to sum and count Id's grouped by date from joining Tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help, I have 2 tables **station_levy** and **market_levy** I'm trying to group all transactions done in both tables, finding the total and counting the number of transactions grouped by date.

The tables are as follows

```
station_levy

| station_levy_id | amount_tendered | transaction_datetime |
| --------------- | --------------- | -------------------- |
|        1        |       10        |       2021-02-01     |
|        2        |        5        |       2021-02-01     |
|        3        |       10        |       2021-02-03     |
|        4        |       10        |       2021-02-04     |

market_levy

| market_levy_id  | amount_tendered | transaction_datetime |
| --------------- | --------------- | -------------------- |
|        1        |        2        |       2021-02-01     |
|        2        |        3        |       2021-02-02     |
|        3        |        2        |       2021-02-03     |
|        4        |        2        |       2021-02-04     |
```

I tried this but it's not grouping by date

```
SELECT transaction_datetime, amount_tendered
FROM market_levy

UNION ALL

SELECT transaction_datetime, amount_tendered
FROM station_levy 
GROUP BY DATE(transaction_datetime)

ORDER BY DATE(transaction_datetime)
```

Expected result

```
| trans_count     | total_tendered  | transaction_datetime |
| --------------- | --------------- | -------------------- |
|        3        |       17        |       2021-02-01     |
|        1        |        3        |       2021-02-02     |
|        2        |       12        |       2021-02-03     |
|        2        |       12        |       2021-02-04     |
```

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RagingBull I tried to union all and Group by date but its not working

Comment: @Wells. Good! Can you please share that query and output/error you are getting now.

Comment: Union All should be in your query.

Comment: In your query the group by only applies to the second select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION` your tables in a subquery and do aggregation and group by on top of that:

```
select count(1) as trans_count
       ,sum(amount_tendered) as amount_tendered
       ,DATE(transaction_datetime) as transaction_datetime
from
  (select station_levy_id as trans, amount_tendered, transaction_datetime
  from station_levy
  union all
  select market_levy_id as trans, amount_tendered, transaction_datetime
  from market_levy) temp
group by DATE(transaction_datetime)
```

See result in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3866fd/6)